# New schema to store crucial data?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to find solution to mark crucial data in application. One obvious idea is to create a flag like 'not removable', but I want to avoid adding the same column to many tables in db.
So I have the idea to create new schema in which I could store those dates. In this schema I would like to keep all tables that exists in the public with the same constraints.
I found several advantages:

- I can revoke delete privileges for whole schema and allow to delete data only from public schema (not crucial for application),
- I can fast prepare new version of database to test - by truncating everything what's in the public schema (in the second one I've got
  only crucial data),
- I do SELECT's and other operations by the instead of rule, that shows data from both schemas and add a virtual column (only in a
  view) that marks origin of the data,
- I don't have to store id's of rows in the application's config,
- I have logic separation of data (basic and added by the users)

Is it a good idea? Do you see any problems with that?
Is it a good practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As best I can figure out what you're asking, you want to unify two sets of data, one that's important and read-only and another that's unimportant and read/write. You want the two to appear to be one table to the application. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. For all tables in the public schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this, the simple approach is to use table inheritance to make it transparent to select statements, and keep the writes redirected by rules.  This is the way table partitioning is done, but you could be partitioning based on the need for different permissions in this case rather than key.